# C++ Missing type specifier: syntax error

Tags: c++, windows, hook, detours

I hook a function with windows detours in C++.

I get an error in following code:

```
void (*asmFunction)(const char *text);
void hookFunction(const char *text) {
    __asm nop;
    asmFunction(text);
}
asmFunction = (void (__cdecl *)(const char *))DetourFunction((PBYTE)0x433A90, (PBYTE)&hookFunction);
```

The compiler (MSVC++ 2008) says:

> error C4430: Missing type specifier - int assumed. Hint: "default-int" is not supported in C++. *Yadda yadda …*
>   error C2373: 'asmFunction': redefinition with different specifiers
>   error C2440: 'in initialization': 'void (__cdecl *)(const char *)' cannot be converted to 'int'. There is no context in which this conversion is valid.

The code worked yesterday. What's wrong with it? How can I fix it without destructing the hook?

Comment: C++ errors are scary by themselves. More so when they're in German :)

Comment: Try using a typedef to make this more readable and maintainable.

Comment: We need some German Folks rightaway to make sense of the error! where is @Xeo usually he lurks around here this time :)

Comment: @Als: Or, you know, lookup the error code instead.

Answer (score 4):

This expression needs to be within a function, e.g.

```
int main() {
    asmFunction = (void (__cdecl *)(const char *))DetourFunction(
        (PBYTE)0x433A90, (PBYTE)&hookFunction
    );
    // ...
}
```

Go read [a book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).